# it's possible do Row Level Security for Polybase external table in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, view, external-tables, polybase

I need to enable row-level security on an external table pointing to Oracle in SQL Server 2019.

I have only been able to find that it is possible to do it with external tables in Azure Synapse.

Is there any mechanism or alternative like the use of view to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this, it is possible if you install SQL Server 2019 CU7 or higher: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security

Comment: Yes, it was a version problem